# JSONView library in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use JSONView for the JSON blob I get and display in Json path for each key. 
This library does it: https://github.com/bhollis/jsonview/
As this is written in typescript I want something in javascript. Can some one help with simple example how to get to the following image type with JSON Path

Example JSON:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "0123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "0123-4567-8910"
    }
  ]
}
```

Want it to be like this: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/588VZ.png)

Comment: Compile the library to JavaScript, use it like any other JS file.

Comment: I am not sure how to start?